# OxyPlot heatmap rectangle comments

Tags: c#, f#, oxyplot

Lately I've been working with OxyPlot library doing some charts. I was wondering if I can have a heatmap with comments for each one of the rectangles. looking forward to an answer.

Comment: http://docs.oxyplot.org/en/latest/models/series/HeatMapSeries.html

Comment: do you use F# or C#?

Comment: @Foggy I use F# but I am overriding some C# code to make some things work out

Comment: great, can we continue discuss in the [SO F# chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51909/f)(it's a good place and it will allow find the answer quickly)?

Comment: (just ping me when (if) you come)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: This is how it looks]I finally found that I needed to make a new class and extend the heatmap series and override the RenderLabels method in order to change its functionality.

```
protected override void RenderLabels(IRenderContext rc, OxyRect rect)
    {
        var clip = this.GetClippingRect();
        int m = this.Data.GetLength(0);
        int n = this.Data.GetLength(1);
        double fontSize = (rect.Height / n) * this.LabelFontSize;

        double left = this.X0;
        double right = this.X1;
        double bottom = this.Y0;
        double top = this.Y1;

        var s00 = this.Orientate(this.Transform(left, bottom)); // disorientate
        var s11 = this.Orientate(this.Transform(right, top)); // disorientate

        double sdx = (s11.X - s00.X) / (m - 1);
        double sdy = (s11.Y - s00.Y) / (n - 1);

        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                var point = this.Orientate(new ScreenPoint(s00.X + (i * sdx), s00.Y + (j * sdy))); // re-orientate
                var v = GetValue(this.Data, i, j);
                var color = this.ColorAxis.GetColor(v);
                var hsv = color.ToHsv();
                var textColor = hsv[2] > 0.6 ? OxyColors.Black : OxyColors.White;
                var label = this.Labels[i, j];
                rc.DrawClippedText(
                    clip,
                    point,
                    label,
                    textColor,
                    this.ActualFont,
                    fontSize,
                    500,
                    0,
                    HorizontalAlignment.Center,
                    VerticalAlignment.Middle);
            }
        }
    }
```